# 外部からアクセスされないインスタンス変数を、private attr_reader 指定する意味はありますか？

Tags: ruby

とあるサービスクラスのオブジェクトにおいて、外部からアクセスされないインスタンス変数に対して、 private な attr_reader を設定して、プライベートメソッドとしてアクセスすることに、メリットはありますでしょうか？

それとも、そのような attr_reader は無駄なので、そのような指定を行う意味はないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

typoに気づきやすいというメリットがあると思います。

直接インスタンス変数を使う場合typoをしても値が `nil` なだけでその場では何も起こらないですが、
`private` な `attr_reader` の場合typoしていると `NoMethodError` で即座に気づけます。